# Change height of TTTableViewCell dynamically

Tags: iphone, three20

I am using TTTableViewController class. I have added the UIView of height 100 to the Table cell initially. The height of UIView changes dynamically and I have to change the height of cell also. But height of the cell doesnt chnages. please remember I am ?Using Three 20. Thanks in advance for valuable response.

Answer (score 0):

For TTTableViewCell

do it in didLoad or init method

```
    self.variableHeightRows = YES;
```

and use the below function.

```
    + (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView rowHeightForObject:(id)object;
       {
           return 80; //value can be changed
        }
```

Comment: @RaviNalawade if that answer worked for you then pls mark it as correct.It helps other people also who are having the same problem.thank you..

Answer (score 0):

Have you Enabled this while creating row Dynamically??

```
BOOL variableHeightRows = YES
```

You can refer [this link](http://api.three20.info/interface_t_t_table_view_controller.php), hope it may help you. :))

Or try this :-

```
-(CGFloat)tableView :(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
   // return (the value for the row)
 }
```

but for this you must implement its Delegate i.e. UITableViewDataSource.

Comment: Yes I have set variableHeightRows= YES.

Comment: I am using the TTTableView not the UITableView. Is the above method is applicable in this TTTableView?

Comment: follow this link it has the answer you need i think so  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007271/three20-framework-how-to-change-default-row-height-tttableview

Answer (score 0):

use the below delegate method to adjust table row height.

```
-(CGFloat)tableView :(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
return 50; //the required table row height
}
```

Comment: I am using the TTTableView not the UITableView. Is the above method is applicable in this TTTableView?